# Controlling Multiple Switch button in Android

Tags: android, android-switch

I'm Building a simple profile manager android application Using Switch Button in Android.
There are 3 switches named General,Silent and Vibrate.
Problem is all 3 switches are working together

[image]

I want the General Switch to be disabled when the silent switch is activated and silent to be disable when the general Switch is activated.

Where is my Code and what should be added ?

```
general = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.generalSwitch);
    silent  = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.silentSwitch);
    vibrate = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.vibrateSwitch);

    myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);




    general.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"General Mode Activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



    silent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Silent Mode Activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    vibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Vibrate Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with this:

```
    general.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                silent.setChecked(false);
            }

        }
    });

    silent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                general.setChecked(false);
            }

        }
    });
```

if general switch is inactive and silent switch is active, when you press general, this change your state to active and you change silent switch to inactive.

Answer (score 1):

When you say disabled first thing I imagine is switch can not to be touchable. Like in the picture. 
[image: Like this example]

If you want to do something like this you should add in setOnClickListener block 
something like ;

```
silent.setEnabled(false)
```

But I think you meant that; 
When the silent switch is ON general switch is OFF and when the general switch is ON silent switch is OFF
Than you can use setChecked method.
Like this;

```
 general.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"General Mode Activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 silent.setChecked(false);
        }
    });



    silent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Silent Mode Activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 general.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
```